# 2 dimensional table with indexing by string(object)

Tags: c#, string, collections, indexed, dimensional

I've got a problem i need to create 2 dimensional table which will be indexed by string for example:

```
table["London","Cambridge"] = 120;
```

or jagged:

```
table["London"]["Cambridge"] = 120;
```

How to declare Collection or array that can handle this?
I found solution but im not sure it is the best.

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>> test = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>>();
```

But  when i wanna create a new value i need to initialize new dictionary, so why i thing that solution is not the rightest:

```
table.Add("London", new Dictionary<string, int> {{"Cambridge",120}});
```

So how in the best way create 2 dimensional array indexed by string (mayby create new class that can handle this)?

Comment: Would a DataTable be appropriate here?  Is the number of strings being used ever liable to change?

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a MultiKey-dictionary once, lets see, [here](https://sharpkom.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/sharpkom/SharpKom/MultipleKeyDictionary.cs) it is.

You can get or set an element by two keys like this `dictionary["key1", "key2"]`.

**Edit:**
But I suppose with the Tuple type in .NET 4 you can use a Tuple as key instead of using nested dictionaries.

```
public class Dictionary<TKey1, TKey2, TValue> : Dictionary<Tuple<TKey1, TKey2>, TValue>
...
```

Comment: That's not a very good implementation, but it will probably work for his purposes.